# Custom selector in PlayWright

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-sharp

Is it possible to add a custom selector in Playwright? (preferabele in C#)

For example, our application uses the custom attribute `[data-automation-name=SOMENAME]` in the HTML and it's a bit cumbersome to write every time:

```cs
page.FillAsync("[data-automation-name=SOMENAME1]", "1");
page.FillAsync("[data-automation-name=SOMENAME2]", "2");
page.FillAsync("[data-automation-name=SOMENAME3]", "3");
```

I prefer to write something like this:

```cs
page.FillAsync("$SOMENAME1", "1");
page.FillAsync("$SOMENAME2", "2");
page.FillAsync("$SOMENAME3", "3");
```

I searched the [docs](https://playwright.dev/dotnet) and GitHub repos without success.

Comment: I dont know how to do it in C# but here is how You can create Your own selector in node:
[Playwright official](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/api/class-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is ...

```
private async Task FillNameAsync(string name, string value)
    => await page.FillAsync($"[data-automation-name={name}]", value);

await FillNameAsync("SOMENAME1", "1");
await FillNameAsync("SOMENAME2", "2");
await FillNameAsync("SOMENAME3", "3");
```

Comment: Would be even better to declare `FillNameAsync` method not being async by leaving out the `await` and removing `async`, since it is not necessary within the scope of `FillNameAsync`. The `await` is required only when calling this method, like in the three lines below its declaration.